# Google Admob integration error

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode6

i use the latest version of SDK for iphone integration but it give me this error.[image]

Comment: What version of AdMob SDK do you use?

Comment: 7.2.1 version of SDK i use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the AdMob Framework from your project, clean your project, and import the AdMob Framework again.

and Download the Framework here [enter link description here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download)

```
#import <GoogleMobileAds/GADBannerView.h>
#import <GoogleMobileAds/GADRequest.h>
```

Comment: 'GoogleMobileAds/GADAdNetworkExtras.h' file not found

Comment: it's my pleasure buddy

Answer (score 0):

As it's now a Framework. You have to include it like this :
 `@import GoogleMobileAds;`